# Python and selenium clicking Continue button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

how can I access this Contine button using selenium [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic69b.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFSrb.png)

Continue

I want to click on this button this is what i tried

```
continue_button = driver.find_element("name","Continue")
continue_button.click()
```

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: What happens when your code runs? Does it throw an error message? If so, edit your question and add the full stack trace as text indicating what line it's failing on. If it otherwise doesn't work, explain what is going wrong.